# I deleted my home folder, now I can't log in through Unity

Tags: unity, login, lightdm, login-screen, ecryptfs

I deleted my home folder when followed the steps in:

```
ecryptfs-setup-private --undo
```

I'm not worried about the data or anything, but I can't log in through Unity anymore.

I switched to root in the terminal and did:

```
mkdir home/username
chown username:username home/username
```

I can log in fine through the terminal, but not through Unity. It just goes to a black screen temporarily and goes back to the log in screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you forget a leading `/` in the path?  If you did, you might have created the directory in root's home directory (`/root`) and not in the root directory `/`.

Comment: I tried with the leading `/`. It said folder already exists.

Comment: Does the system know that the new directory is to be used as your home directory? what does `getent passwd $(id -u)` say?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to cleanup your ecryptfs setup and startover.

You can do this by removing the `/home/.ecryptfs/username` folder.